# How to convert part of file to lowercase?

Tags: gvim, find-and-replace

Using gVIM on XP

How can I convert the left side of this file to lowercase while keeping right side unchanged?

```
%s/**what goes here?**/g

CONVERTTOLOWERCASE###Keep CaSe
AAAA###AeiOu
BBBB###qWerTy
```

Desired Results

```
converttolowercase###Keep CaSe
aaaa###AeiOu
bbbb###qWerTy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command you are looking for:

```
%s/^[^#]\+/\=toupper(submatch(0))/
```

See:

- `:help tolower()`
- `:help sub-replace-special`
- `:help sub-replace-expression`
- `:help submatch()`